# How to be able to write to a textbox side-by-side names of the items which are find inside Listbox in C#?

Tags: c#

How to be able to write to a textbox side-by-side names of the items which are find inside Listbox in C#?

Regards,

Comment: What's "side-by-side" mean here?  Two names per line?  Just separated names by some delimiter?  Is this WinForms?  WPF?

Comment: @itsmatt- I wanted to say just seperated names by some delimiter.BTW,I'm using WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
foreach (string s in Listbox.SelectedItems) 
{
   TextBox.Text += s + ", ";   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i under stand correctly use:

```
    foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
    {
       textbox1.text = textbox1.text + s;
       textbox1.text = textbox1.text + "\r\n";
    }
```